# rostopic echo offset command

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"rostopic echo --offset /topic_name" command displays time in messages as offset from current time (eg to calculate lag/latency).
Is the resulting time offset in kernel ticks, or milliseconds, or nanoseconds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286160/rostopic-echo-offset-command/) by [uuik](https://answers.ros.org/users/34262/uuik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Time in  ROS have a standard representation :
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time

You can test is with some simple command :

```
roscore&
rostopic pub /topic_name geometry_msgs/PoseStamped "header: auto
pose:
  position:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0"  -r 1 &
rostopic echo --offset /topic_name/header
```

The result of those commands will be :

```
seq: 6
stamp:
  secs: -71
  nsecs: 997840166
frame_id: ''
---
seq: 7
stamp:
  secs: -72
  nsecs: 998944997
frame_id: ''
---
seq: 8
stamp:
  secs: -73
  nsecs: 998456955
frame_id: ''
---
```

There is indeed 1 second of offset between messages (1 second because of the `-r 1` in rostopic pub), displayed as a negative value because the message stamp is behind the current timestamp.
If you fill the stamp with 'now' value every 1 second, the duration will be -1 secs everytime.

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1